# polymorphism in c++, loss of type in vector of parent class

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism

I have a class A, which is parent to classes B and C.
And a class X, which is a parent to Y and Z.

```
class A {};
class B : public A {};
class C : public A {};


class X
{
    void foo(A) { std:: cout << "A"; }
};

class Y : public X
{
    void foo(B) {std::cout << "B"; }
};

class Z : public X
{
    void foo(c) {std<<cout <<"C"; }
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    C c;

    Y y;
    Z z;

    y.foo(b);//prints B // b is a B, and Y::foo takes a B, hence print B
    y.foo(c);//prints A // mismatch between types, fall back and print A
    z.foo(b);//prints A // mismatch between types, fall back and print A
    z.foo(c);//prints C // c is a C, and Y::foo takes a C, hence print C

    std::vector<A> v;
    v.push_back(b);
    v.push_back(c);

    //In this loop, it always prints A, but *this is what I want to change* 
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
    {
        z.foo(v.at(i));
        y.foo(v.at(i));
    }
}
```

Is it possible to get the items to print the same result as the hard coded calls?
Meaning that I will treat them as their original type, and not its parent type?
or once I put them int a vector of A they will forever be of type A?

Comment: `y.foo(c); // print A`. Surely this is not the desired behaviour? I think you want it to print "B"? I think you need to clarify your desired behaviour. Given `p.foo(q)`, do you want the printed text to depend on the type of q, or on the type of p, or on both? Consider all 9 options `{x,y,z}.foo({a,b,c});` and tell us what your desired behaviour is.

Comment: the desired behaviour are the first prints
Meaning y.foo(b) should print B, and y.foo(c) should call the base class x.foo() and print A

Comment: OK. So in `p.foo(q)`: If the (dynamic) type of q is the same as the the type of the parameter to `p::foo`, then that type should be printed. In all other cases, it should print "A".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are seeing is **[Object Slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing)**.
You are storing object of Derived class in an vector which is supposed to store objects of Base class, this leads to Object slicing and the derived class specific members of the object being stored get sliced off, thus the object stored in the vector just acts as object of Base class.

**Solution:**

You should store pointer to object of Base class in the vector:

```
vector<X*>
```

By storing a pointer to Base class there would be no slicing and you can achieve the desired polymorphic behavior as well by making the functions `virtual`.
The right approach is to use a suitable **[Smart pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706192/which-kind-of-pointer-do-i-use-when)** instead of storing a raw pointer in the vector. That will ensure you do not have to manually manage the memory, **[RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization)** will do that for you automatically.

Comment: You mean, change the vector to vector<A*>?

Comment: I believe you also need to make the functions virtual as @vasile states, but this is definitely slicing as well.

Comment: @greg: The OP already stated that the functions are `virtual` only problem is Op stores objects and not pointers.

Comment: I don't see any `virtual` in the question. And I don't see any method calls to to A or B or C. The only methods calls are `foo`, inside X,Y,Z.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: Check OPs response to vasile's answer.

Comment: @Bg1987, you said `y.foo(c); // print A`. Surely this is not the desired behaviour? I think you want it to print "B"? I think you need to clarify your desired behaviour. Given `p.foo(q)`, do you want the printed text to depend on the type of q, or on the type of p, or on both? Consider all 9 options `{x,y,z}.foo({a,b,c});` and tell us what your desired behaviour is.

Comment: .. yes, but `virtual` functions in X,Y,Z aren't (I think) relevant. In order for `vector<A*>` to work as expected, there must be virtual functions in `A`. (At least, I think so until I am 100% clear what the goal is).

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: I am not sure what OP intends but it is clear what the problem is and the answer points it out, The basic problem is you need to store pointers to objects of the base class in the container and then provide virtual methods to achieve the polymorphic behavior,which base class i think the OP can decide based on his needs.

Comment: There are two distinct class hierachies, `A->B->C` and `X->Y->Z`, in the question. It should be a `vector<A*>`, not `vector<X*>`. It can't compile with `vector<X*> v` because the code then attempts to `v.push_back(&b)`, where b is of type `B`, and B is not a subclass of X.

Comment: i.e. I think @Grizzly's is the only correct answer I've seen so far.

Answer (score 1):

This is called **slicing**. When you `push_back` your elements into a `std::vector<A>` it basically copies the `elements` into newly constructed instances of `A`. Therefore the part ofs of the object, which come from the derived class will be lost ("sliced off").

In order to avoid slicing you need to use a container which stores pointers instead of elements, so you should use a **`std::vector<A*>`** or if your elements are heap allocated preferably a vector of some sort of smartpointer (`std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr` in C++11, `boost::shared_ptr` or `std::tr1::shared_ptr` otherwise).

However your code won't work as written, even if you change that:
`X`, `Y` and `Z` all take their parameter by value, while all elements in your vector will have the type `A*`, so dereferencing them would yield `A`, so it will still call the wrong method. This could be solved by changing the signatures to always take `A&` or `A*` and using `dynamic_cast` to try casting that into the type:

```
class X
{
    void foo(A*) { std:: cout << "A"; }
};

class Y : public X
{
    void foo(A* p) { 
      if ( dynamic_cast<B*>(p) ) std::cout << "B"; // requires virtual methods in A
      else                   X::foo(p);
    }
};

class Z : public X
{
    void foo(A*){ 
      if ( dynamic_cast<C*>(p) ) std::cout << "C"; // requires virtual methods in A
      else                   X::foo(p);
    }
};
```

Of course `dynamic_cast` is a bit costly, but if that's a problem you might want to rethink your design. Furthermore you need to ensure that `A, B, C` contain some `virtual` methods (a `virtual destructor` would be a good idea here anyways), since otherwise `dynamic_cast` won't work)

Comment: I think you've nailed it, it should print "B" or "C" *if and only if* there is a match between the dynamic type of the parameter and the type desired by X,Y,Z. I've edited the question a little, based on comments from the OP.