# statically casting parent to child C++

Tags: c++, casting, polymorphism, static-cast

I have a parent class and a child class which has a function specific to it that the parent class does not have. I create a vector of type Parent and add an object of type Child to it. I know for sure that said item is a child, so I attempt to use a static_cast to create a pointer to it in order to use its child specific function, but it refuses to convert giving the error described in the code below.

```
#include <vector>

//Parent Class
class Parent {
public:
    Parent() {};
};

//Child Class
class Child : public Parent
{
public:
    void childSpecificFunction() {};
};

int main()
{
    //I know for a fact that the item is a child
    std::vector<Parent> items;
    items.push_back(Child());

    //Static cast to use child specific function doesn't work
    Child* childPtr = static_cast<Child*>(items[0]);
    childPtr->childSpecificFunction();

    //Gives intellisence error: no suitable conversion from "Parent" to "Child *" exists
}
```

Why is this happening? Is there a better approach to this sort of thing?

Thanks.

Comment: `//I know for a fact that the item is a child` It's not. Google object slicing.

Comment: Does it compile actually? "Intellisense" is fooling you a lot, unless (background) indexing finished.

Comment: Also, reread the part of your book that explains pointers, you cannot just cast an object to a pointer to itself.

Comment: @BaummitAugen so, adding the Child to a Parent vector slices it therefore removing the child specific functions and members? If this is true, is there a better way to group both parents and children alike in one group?

Comment: @JacobOaks See for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/8790210/3002139 (That's also a potential duplicate if you agree, though not exact enough for me to hammer that.)

Comment: If you want runtime polymorphism (a collection of parents some of which may really be children), you usually need pointers, just because the things you're storing may not be the same size. Try `vector<unique_ptr<Parent>>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is this happening

Let's dissect it:

```
int main()
{
    //I know for a fact that the item is a child
    std::vector<Parent> items;
    items.push_back(Child()); // <<<< You are copying and slicing here

    //Static cast to use child specific function doesn't work
    Child* childPtr = static_cast<Child*>(items[0]);
    childPtr->childSpecificFunction(); // <<<<< undefined behavior

    //Gives intellisence error: no suitable conversion from "Parent" to "Child *" exists
}
```

---

A suitable fix

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Parent>> items;
    items.push_back(std::make_unique<Child>());  // <<< working with pointers,
                                                 //     no slicing.

    Child* childPtr = static_cast<Child*>(items[0].get());
    childPtr->childSpecificFunction();
 }
```

Comment: This seems to work perfectly for my example. Are there any reservations I should know about this method before using it in larger projects?

Comment: @JacobOaks I would encourage you to use exactly that solution (may be changing the smart pointer type depending on your use cases). There are no _reservations_, smart pointers are thread safe and secure., just use them.

Comment: @JacobOaks Recommend a quick bit of research on `static_cast` vs  `dynamic_cast` before applying this in a larger project. If you have one child class, you may have two or more child classes (and if not, why bother with inheritance at all?) and no way to tell them apart.

Comment: @user4581301 _"you may have two or more child classes"_ `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Parent>> items;` perfectly fit's that situation.

Comment: Yes it does, but `static_cast<Child*>(items[0].get());` can quietly go awry if `items[0].get()` returns `Child2*` rather than `Child*`. `static_cast` removes almost all of the compiler's defenses.

Comment: @user4581301 If the OP explores these smart pointer facilities I'd expect they'll also see [`std::weak_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr), which is appropriate to fix that problem with `get()`.

Comment: No it won't. Different problem. I'm worried about using `static_cast` to treat a `Child` as a `Child2` and suffering unknown bizarreness at runtime because the types are different. `dynamic_cast` will at least make the failure to convert obvious by returning `nullptr`. Taking advantage of `virtual` functions is probably an even better solution than casting.

Comment: `dynamic_cast` cannot be used unless the class has at least one virtual function

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you are trying to store object and then cast it to Pointer to Child*

```
#include <vector>

//Parent Class
class Parent {
public:
    Parent() {};
};

//Child Class
class Child : public Parent
{
public:
    void childSpecificFunction() {};
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Parent*> items;
    items.push_back(new Child());

    Child* childPtr = static_cast<Child*>(items[0]);
    childPtr->childSpecificFunction();


}
```

Another approach would be casting the Address of the Child object

```
#include <vector>

//Parent Class
class Parent {
public:
    Parent() {};
};

//Child Class
class Child : public Parent
{
public:
    void childSpecificFunction() {};
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Parent> items;
    items.push_back(Child());

    Child* childPtr = static_cast<Child*>(&(items[0]));
    childPtr->childSpecificFunction();

}
```